# path.rename сохраняет файлы в корневую папку

Tags: python, pathlib

Есть скрипт для переименования файлов по порядку, которые находятся по пути ***"D:/files"***.
По окончанию работы скрипта файлы сохраняются в корневую папку, в которой находится **main.py**

Как сохранить переименованные файлы в папку в которой они лежат изначально, тобишь в ***"D:/files"*** ?

```
import pathlib

folder = "D:/files"
filename = input('Введите имя файлов:')

path = pathlib.Path(folder)
for i, path in enumerate(path.glob('*.jpg')):
    new_name = str(filename) + ' ' + '[' + str(i) + ']' + path.suffix
    path.rename(new_name)
```

Comment: Добавить к имени имя папки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rename` на самом деле не переименование (не только переименование), а перемещение.

Чтобы при перемещении файл остался в той же папке, в которой был, нужно к имени слева добавить путь к папке. Например, взять `path`, который у вас снаружи цикла:

```
base_path = pathlib.Path(folder)
for i, path in enumerate(base_path.glob('*.jpg')):
    new_name = str(filename) + ' ' + '[' + str(i) + ']' + path.suffix
    path.rename(base_path / new_name)
```

Либо брать исходный путь к файлу из path внутри цикла:

```
path.rename(path.parent / new_name)
```

По поводу формирования имени файла:

1. `filename` не нужно оборачивать в `str`, т.к. `input` и так вернул строку
2. В целом, удобнее использовать форматирование строк (например, f-строки), а не склеивать из кусков

Можно переписать формирование нового имени файла так:

```
new_name = f"{filename} [{i}]{path.suffix}"
```